# awk calling in python script responding as file cannot be open/read

Tags: python, python-2.7, awk

I am trying to open a file via python script by calling `awk` by giving folder and file name as `%s`.

---

```
import commands    
genotype = 'rice'

filename = 'model.txt'    
dear = commands.getoutput('''awk '{print $0}' /home/angad/Desktop/Python_result/%s/%s''') % (genotype,filename)

print dear
```

But it is returning as:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file '/home/angad/Desktop/Python_result/rice/model.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

The concerned file is indeed present there.
As if, I write input file path directly instead of `raw_input(%s)`, it successfully open and print the file content.

Comment: So, if you type "stat /home/angad/Desktop/Python_result/rice/model.txt", what do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your parentheses is in the wrong place.  Try:

```
dear = commands.getoutput('''awk '{print $0}' /home/angad/Desktop/Python_result/%s/%s''' % (genotype,filename))
```

Or better yet:

```
cmd_str = '''awk '{print $0}' /home/angad/Desktop/Python_result/%s/%s''' % (genotype,filename)
dear = commands.getoutput(cmd_str)
```

The reason the error message shows the correct file path in your original example is that the result of getoutput, which included the error message with the %s formats still present, was being substituted before being printed.  Very misleading!

Comment: Oh, man, the result of that erroneous command was a string, and the error message was interpolated by the values he wanted to use and wasn't. Whoa. Nice.

Comment: OP, this is why you should be using `subprocess`, not commands. Stderr is not the same as stdout, and treating them the same is a recipe for errors.

Comment: Thanks Tom for your nice troubleshoot, it was indeed very misleading as I was every time cross checking my typing error for wrong file name/path.

Comment: Chad you suggested right that subprocess should be used to avoid such confusions. Thanks